# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClientConfig

Tags: java, spring, cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm using Spring Cloud Eureka and creating the project using *Spring Initializr* (http://start.spring.io/). The generated POM user **Eureka Finchley.RC2** with **Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE**. When I add the annotation `@EnableEurekaServer` in the main class, the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` also, and I start the server with following command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I receive the exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClientConfig
```

the following is the pom.xml generated by the Initializr:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>it.javaboss</groupId>
<artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>api-gateway</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: just check GC(http://grepcode.com/search/?query=EurekaClientConfig), this class exists in `eureka-client`. You need check whether it exists in your dependency hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I found the eureka-clien-1.9.2.jar in my local maven repository is ZERO length file, so I deleted it and re-download the dependency, all is ok!

Answer (score 0):

hope to help someone - i had same issue java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/netflix/discovery/converters/XmlXStream when launch eureka server, version i used springboot 2.0.3.RELEASE and spring-cloud.version Finchley.RELEASE. i resolved it by rename my local maven repo user-folder.m2\repository, fresh load a new local maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>eureka-server</finalName>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

As 'rosa lu' said, when launch eureka server I have the similar issue as below: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/netflix/discovery/converters/XmlXStream
`SpringBoot=2.0.5.RELEASE`
`SpringCloud.version=Finchley.SR1`
As 'rosa lu' said, I change my local maven repository to a new path, and rebuild my project, then solve the problem
I hope my answer can help anyone who has the same issue .

Answer (score -1):

**Make sure** that

1. You should select only *Eureka Server* using *spring Initializr*
   while creating eureka server project.
2. Have these properties (in **application.properties**)

   ```
   eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
   eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
   ```

   These will disable the client aspect the the eureka server.
3. You might be having `com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClientConfig` imported somewhere in your project. So organize your imports once.

Comment: I selected just Eurika Server e Spring Cloud Config. Even disabling the client aspect from the application.properties I have the same issue.

Comment: @user2834179 did you tried the third one? Is it compilation error?

Comment: Thanks, I added the dependency eureka-client but now I have a new error:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.Configuration

Comment: @user2834179 I did not indicate you to add eureka-client. Can you post the relevant code as well?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved the propblem in two different solution:

1.adding two more dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
        <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

2.renaming application.yml in bootstrap.yml and disabling autoregistration:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

but in this second way I still need to add the dependency to jettison:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to add these dependencies manually. It worked for me without adding eureka-client and jettison dependencies. But glad you got it working.